# Javascript toggle / display not working on my mobile

Tags: javascript, android, ios, twitter-bootstrap

I use a script to toggle a div on click. The problem is, that the contents of the div won't show on mobile (I tried Android and iOS). I have tried to figure out what I did wrong, but I couldn't figure it out. It does work on desktop (Safari, Chrome etc.)

### My script

```
var toggle = function() {
var mydiv = document.getElementById('newpost');
if (mydiv.style.display === 'none' || mydiv.style.display === '')
mydiv.style.display = 'block';
else
mydiv.style.display = 'none'
}
```

### My HTML

```
<div id="newpost">
CONTENT
</div>
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style ="width: 100%; 
margin-bottom: 20px" value="Click here"  
onclick="this.style.display='none';toggle();" alt="Click here">
</input>
```

==

Solution

I was using a CSS animation. This didn't work on mobile. So I removed the animation and now everything works!

Comment: are you using any bootstrap css etc in your code. if the code is responsive, it might hide some of the div when it xs device i.e. mobile device. In that case we need to enable them for small devices.

Comment: I do use bootstrap css. Do you know how I can make the div visible for small devices?

Answer (score 0):

When you are using bootstrap, .hidden-xs may be set and you are not able to view the div in the small screen. you need to set .visible-xs which will make it visible on extra small devices and .visible-sm for small devices.

For eg.

```
  <div class="hidden-xs col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
  // when hidden-xs class it applied,  it will not be seen in small device.  
  </div>
```

to make the div visible in small device you need to set it as

```
 <div class= "visible-xs col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
   // when visible-xs class it applied,  it will be seen in small device
 </div>
```

Comment: How do I change this?

Comment: I see that I haven't defined the hidden-xs for my div. So this doesn't seem to be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem to be using Bootstrap, there is a better way to do this. This method requires jQuery and bootstrap.js.

```
<div id="post" class="collapse">
   CONTENT 
</div>    
<a href="#" id="btn" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#post">Click here</a>
```

[Demo in JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b1eb89La/)

Comment: Hi @vlarsson, unfortunately that doesn't work if I implement this in my page.  (I included the jQuery library)

Comment: Have you included bootstrap.js after jQuery as well?

Comment: Hi @vlarsson, the problem was my CSS animation. This didn't work on mobile.